# Laravel validation error

Tags: php, html, laravel, validation, routes

Why my validation is not working, but if i commend the validation, the code will successfully running. 
[Here is my Controller][1]

function changepassword(Request $req){

```
    $this->validate(
        $req,
        [
            'currpassword' => 'required | min:5',
            'newpassword' => 'required | min:5',
            'confirmnewpassword' => 'required| same:newpassword |min:5' 
        ]);

    // Validasinya gajalan

    $id = $req->input('id');
    $data = User::find($id);

    $currpassword = $req->input('currpassword');
    $newpassword = $req->input('newpassword');
    $confirmnewpassword = $req->input('confirmnewpassword');

    $currpass = $req->input('currpassword'); // password yang lama

    $currpasshash = Hash::make('currpassword');

    if (Hash::check($currpass , $data->password)) { 
        $data->password = Hash::make($newpassword);
        $data->save();
        return redirect('profile'); 

    }
    else{
        return redirect('changepassword');
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
function changepassword(Request $req) {
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'currpassword' => 'required|min:5',
        'newpassword' => 'required|min:5',
        'confirmnewpassword' => 'required|same:newpassword|min:5' 
    ]);
}
```

Displaying The Validation Errors

```
<h1>Create Post</h1>

@if ($errors->any())
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <ul>
           @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
               <li>{{ $error }}</li>
           @endforeach
      </ul>
   </div>
@endif
```

For more information visit [Validation in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)

I hope this will help you...

Comment: in which line or which method?

Comment: i mean method validate does not exist, this is the error message "BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method validate does not exist."

Comment: did you import validator?  use Validator

Comment: im using this one 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;' 
it's correct?

Comment: yes, but use this at the top of your script instead of the long namespaced Facade.   use Validator;

Comment: it works by itself, i didn't change anything haha, btw thanku for ur help bro!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

You have passed wrong parameter to your validate method, try this,

```
$this->validate(
    $req->all(), [
        'currpassword' => 'required | min:5',
        'newpassword' => 'required | min:5',
        'confirmnewpassword' => 'required| same:newpassword |min:5' 
    ]);
```

Comment: it didnt works, :( the result was an error message 
"Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given,"

Answer (score 1):

There is a space in between the field named `newpassword` and pip `|` symbol and `laravel` identifies the field name as "newpassword " instead of "newpassword" which results always in error.

Remove the space and try:

```
'confirmnewpassword' => 'required | same:newpassword| min:5'
```

Comment: it didn't affect anything :( . the result is still back to change password's page when i click change password button

Comment: @KennyNataniel can you confirm whether the redirection to change password page is happening because of **validate** function or of the following line **return redirect('changepassword');**